# How do I add a new field for every object in the array?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

How do I add a new `shortText` field to each object inside the `articles` array?

```
articles.forEach((article) => {
        request(article.link, (err, response, html) => {
          if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const textData = $('.ssrcss-hmf8ql-BoldText');
            textData.each((index, element) => {
              article.shortText = $(element).text();
            });
          }
        });
      });
```

Example articles array

```
[
  {
    headline: 'Scale of Russian mercenary mission in Libya exposed',
    link: 'https://bbc.com/news/world-africa-58009514'
  },
  {
    headline: 'Afghan president rallies Taliban-besieged city',
    link: 'https://bbc.com/news/world-asia-58170847'
  }
]
```

I want to loop through the above arrray and add the shortText field to each object

Comment: Whats the behaviour now? Can you share a sample input data and output data?

Comment: Your current code is permanenlty reassigning `article.shortText` so at the end it is assigned to the lest value of `textData`. Also, you might not need jQuery. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: First of all, you're calling `request` inside `forEach` witches a bad thing cause `forEach` doesn't wait for async functions to get resolved, you need to use a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//add fullname field in array of objects

/*
arrayOfObjects =arrayOfObjects.map((instanceObject) => ({
        ...instanceObject,
        newfield : values,
        }))
*/

const getUsers = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfrfjgAOIy?indent=2"
  );
  let users = await response.json();

  users = users.map((person) => ({
    ...person,
    fullname: `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`,
  }));

  console.log(users);
};

getUsers();
```